# PHP header redirect issues

Tags: php, facebook

I am facing a peculiar behavior in php header function.

The code below works fine,

```
 header("Location: https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?api_key=148814828480550&next=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com&session_key=2.HP0X33OURpJRDPfkvWYtAQ__.3600.1285146000-1039666914");
```

But when I pass URL as variable, it takes me to facebook page but not back to mysite.

```
$location =  $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => 'mysite.com'));
header("Location: $location");
```

I checked contents of $location, it is same url which is working when given as string.

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: If it is doing different things, then how can it be the same? Can you show us `getLogoutUrl()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be something to do with character encoding

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the following code:-

```
$location = (string) html_entity_decode($facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => 'mysite.com')));
header("Location: $location");
exit();
```

Also please check whether all the query string indexes are available as required along with the same values, when using the above code, which are:-

1. api_key
2. next
3. session_key

When using "`header()`" function, it's necessary to make sure that you are using the "`exit()`" function just after the "`header()`" function call.
Also when using this "`header()`" function, it must be called before outputting any information to the browser (either from PHP or HTML), so it's also better to use the Output Buffering, by calling this function "`ob_start()`" at the very first line of the web page just after the PHP Start Tag (`<?php`).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've had similar problems in the past but exit() solved them.

Answer (score 1):

Not peculiar at all, I forgot to do html_entity_decode($location);

I was echoing the $location, and when I var_dump()'ed it, I found that '&' was actually '& amp;'

Thanks for your answers guys.